# perl dependency management extUtils::Installed list into a container

Tags: perl, dependency-management

In python we have `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Is there something similar in perl?

How can I go from this ExtUtils::Installed list and first install the given perl, and then the correct versioned modules?

```
./installed.pl 
DBD::SQLite - 1.66
DBI - 1.643
Perl - 5.26.1
```

Extutils works on directory paths and .packlists

Comment: You can use `perlbrew` to install `perl`. Then you'd use its `cpan` to install the modules.

Comment: @ikegami this is more on a generic term, I'm splitting up a monolith into a container for each endpoint, So I want to just parse a list.

Comment: That's super easy to do. And once you do, you can use `perlbrew` to install `perl`. Then you'd use its `cpan` to install the modules.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [cpanfile](https://metacpan.org/dist/Module-CPANfile/view/lib/cpanfile.pod) with [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/view/lib/App/cpanminus/fatscript.pm) is a good fit here.

Your container should first install the correct perl (say with [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/)) and then [App::cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus).  After that, a file called **cpanfile** corresponds to the requirements.txt or .packlist above and would look like

```perl
requires 'DBI' => '1.643';
requires 'DBD::SQLite' => '1.66';
```

which you install with `cpanm --installdeps .` will install the rest.

That file formats specifies the minimum versions of those modules, an implicit `>=`.  If you need to pin a specific version, use `==` or avoid a version with `!=`.

The cpanfile format is flexible, allowing you to conditionally install modules using `--with-develop` flags, etc.

Edit: there are those who prefer the speed of [cpm](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpm) over cpanm for installing lots of modules.  It takes some shortcuts (skips tests by default) that shouldn't make a difference in a stable environment.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for cpanm works like a charm. Much more features than default cpan.